# How to filter two model objects by time?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

models.py:

```
class Post(models.Model):
  msg=models.TextField("Shout it out!:")
  college=models.ForeignKey('College')
  time=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

class Feed(models.Model):
  gender = models.CharField(max_length=5, choices=GENDER_CHOICES, default='girl')
  location=models.CharField(max_length=25, choices=LOCATION_CHOICES)
  msg = models.TextField("Message")
  email = models.EmailField("Email:",blank=True, null = True)
  college=models.ForeignKey('College')
  time=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

In templates I wish to show both feeds and posts together in a stream filtered according to time. How do I do it? How can we filter both model objects by time? Is it possible? need Help. Thanks.

Comment: So you want to combine both of them and then order by time? In the end both should be shown in one feed?

Comment: both shud appear in same page.. like how in facebook newsfeed photos,comments,videos n al are displayed together sorted by time.

Comment: see Joe J's answer below. In this case you need a programmatic solution anyway. There is no simple query which can do something like this.

Answer (score 1):

You might consider creating a base class containing the common fields.  Then, you could do a query similar to  BaseFeed.objects.all().order_by('time') and iterate through it in your template, but you could treat each result item as the type that it really is.

```
class BaseFeed(models.Model):
    ....
    msg = models.TextField("Message")
    college=models.ForeignKey('College')
    time=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    ....
```

Here are some snippets that I always refer to when doing something similar.

http://www.djangosnippets.org/snippets/1034/

http://www.djangosnippets.org/snippets/1031/

http://adam.gomaa.us/blog/2009/feb/16/subclassing-django-querysets/